# I'm building a new system, how can I check that the parts I buy are Linux compatible

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm going to buy parts and assembly a desktop computer, and I'd like it to be Linux compatible (Ubuntu). The system specs will be on the higher end (Intel Core i7), and I would like to ensure that it works great running Linux.

How can I ensure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, typing "linux [keywords] support" or "ubuntu [keywords] support" at www.google.com is good enough to find out whether a part is compatible or not. Use the *Past Year* (or even *Past Month*) filter to get only the most recent results. (You may have to press "More search tools* first).

If you need very specific features of the hardware, include that too, e.g. "ubuntu intel wireless "advanced-N 6200" 300Mbps".

Other than that, there are resources like Hardware Compatibility Lists for Linux:

- http://linuxhcl.com/

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to ask the manufacturer via email or the contact form on their web site. This has the community-wide advantage of letting companies know that Linux support is important to their customers.

One tricky way is to look at the components list for a place like AVA computers, who sell PCs with Linux on them. If they use a hardware component, it has a Linux driver.